# Obtener una fraccion de texto especifica con jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo esta variable

```
var data = "<option codigo='1'></option>,<option codigo='2'></option>";
```

y quiero obtener solo lo que esta dentro de `codigo=''` 
es decir obtener `1,2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si alguien te dice que hay que analizarlo con funciones sobre el string, sería un grave error. La forma correcta de hacerlo es llevando el sctring a DOM. En jQuery, usamos [**$.parseHTML()**](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/):

```js
var data = "<option codigo='1'></option>,<option codigo='2'></option>";

var html = $.parseHTML(data);

var resultado = $(html).map(function() {
  return $(this).attr('codigo');
})
.get()
.join(',');

console.log('Resultado:', resultado);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[`$.parseHTML()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/) nos devuelve un array de nodos, sobre el cual usamos [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) para filtrar la información que queremos: en este caso [`.attr('codigo')`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

Comment: @AndreMateoChavez la forma más sencilla es usando regex... Pero son algunas líneas de código, que es imposible responder en un comentario... Mejor en una pregunta nueva (y asegurate de mostrar qué intentaste hasta ahora, por más que no funcione)